# Least Squares with Positive Coefficients Restrictions

Tags: least-squares, constraint, restrictions

Consider the following linear model:
$$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 X_{i1}+\cdots+\beta_k X_{ik}+\varepsilon_i$$

Here, I want to get the estimate with a positive value restriction $\hat{\beta}_1>0$.

That is, the estimate for $\beta_1$ should be positive.

Is it possible to impose the restriction above?

Comment: If you use a Bayesian model with a prior that favors positivity but allows for the possibility of negativity you'll be able to get the posterior probability of positivity while getting efficient estimates.  Sometimes it's better to hedge your bets.

Comment: @Firebug Thank you for the comment!

Comment: @Frank Harrell Though I have little knowledge about a Bayesian model, that sounds interesting.